# Linq List within a list to string

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to do a single linq statement, the following works but want to do it within a single statement.

```
public class ClientProducts
    {
        public string To { get; set; }

        public string ClientFullName { get; set; }

        public string ClientFirstName { get; set; }

        public string ProductNames{ get; set; }
}

 var list =
                    clients.Select(
                        client =>
                            new ClientProducts()
                            {
                                To = client.TelephoneMobile,
                                ClientFirstName = client.FirstName,
                                ClientFullName = client.FullName,
                                //ProductNames= client.Products.Select(p=>p.Name)<-this is what I want
                            }).ToList();

                string productName= string.Empty;
                foreach (var client in clients)
                {
                    foreach (var p in client.Products)
                    {
                        productName+= Name+ ",";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: did you try my approach?

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
//ProductNames= client.Products.Select(p=>p.Name)
```

with

```
ProductNames = string.Join(",", client.Products.Select(p=>p.Name))
```